# How to call exported function inside the same file

Tags: node.js

I have faced a problem regarding calling an exported function inside the same file.

When I call it then the error shows the following.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: findOrCreateMedia is not defined
```

where `findOrCreateMedia` is my function. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function functionName() { ... };
    
exports.functionName = functionName;

functionName();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are losing your `this` object reference inside your calling function.
For eg:

```
    module.exports.a = function () {
      return true
    }
    
    module.exports.b = function() {
      return this.a();
    }
```

here you will get the issue because when you call this.a(), it is referencing the `this` object of the `b` function.

To solve this your have to store your `this` object reference somewhere or use the arrow function, because the arrow function doesn't have there own `this` object so it will always reference the outer `this` object

To solve this, modify your function like this

```
    module.exports.a = function () {
      return true
    }
    
    module.exports.b = () => {
      return this.a();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also ES6 import/export function:-

```
const someFunction = (){

...
}


export default someFuntion  ( in the case on single function)
```

When you want to export multiple functions

```
export { someFunction1, someFunction2}.
```

Now the place where you want to import

```
import somFunction from 'filelocation' ( note in case of default exports you need to use the same name of the function)
```

In the case of multiple functions.You can change the function name but keep in mind the order of exports and imports.

```
import { myFunction1,myFunction2} from 'fileLocation'
```